# Substring a result query

Tags: mysql, substring

I'm trying to substring a mysql query result to get my seperate data columns. My delimiter is the character **"||"** that will separate each result.
I'm searching online and can't seem to find a source that will substring a mysql result. I always find that it substring the columns from the table. Is this possible using substring?

I've created 2 tables which is number and sample:

**Table sample**

[image]

**Table number**

[image]

**Here's my query:**

```
SELECT sample.id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(sample.DESCRIPTION, '::', numbers.n), '::', -1) AS DETAIL
FROM numbers
INNER JOIN sample ON CHAR_LENGTH(sample.DESCRIPTION) -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(sample.DESCRIPTION, '::', ''))>=numbers.n-1
ORDER BY id,
         n
```

**Here's my result query**

[image]

**Here's my expected result**

[image]

**Update**

I've tried to do this in PHP and I've made another progress. However, I'm getting an undefined offset.

**Code:**

```
$querydata = "SELECT DESCRIPTION from sample";
$resultdata = $conn->prepare($querydata);
$resultdata->execute();

$storeresult = $resultdata->fetchObject();
$resultquery = $storeresult->DESCRIPTION;


$pieces = explode("::",$resultquery);

$countVal = count($pieces);

$counter = 0;
$counter1 = 1;
$counter2 = 0;


while($counter<$countVal){
$pieces1 = explode("||", $pieces[$counter]);
$pieces2 = explode("||", $pieces[$counter]);
$pieces3 = explode("||", $pieces[$counter2]);


echo $pieces1[0]."<br>"; // detail
echo $pieces2[1]."<br>"; // response


$counter++;
$rowCount++;

}
```

Comment: Show us the sample and expected data.

Comment: Can you write the result, i don't see images.

Comment: I've added the pics